# StreamBridge Final Cannot Be Mocked

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

I am not able to mock StreamBridge in my Unit Tests.

```
@MockBean
private StreamBridge bridge;
```

I get an IllegalStateException due to:

Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Cannot mock/spy class org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :

- final class
  at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockDefinition.createMock(MockDefinition.java:154)

Comment: There are ways to mock final classes -- did you try any of them? Mockito can do it, or powermock/powermockito if you're more old school.

Comment: Sure, you can mock anything IF there is a justifiable reason for it. But in this case it would be over-mocking (mocking because you can, not because you need). As you can see from the answer below there is sufficient testing infrastructure in the underlying framework to avoid over-mocking.

Answer (score 5):

StreamBridge is a final class, With Mockito2 we can mock the final class, but by default this feature is disabled and that need to enable with below steps:

1. Create a directory ‘mockito-extensions’ in src/test/resources/ folder.
2. Create a file ‘org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker’ in ‘src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/’ directory.
3. Write the content 'mock-maker-inline' in org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker file.
4. At test class level use ‘@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)’

Then StreamBridge will be mocked successfully.

Answer (score 4):

I reached out to Oleg who authored the StreamBridge class and he basically said that:

> We should not be making StreamBridge open to simply accommodate some testing framework. If anything it should be the other way around.

Also, Oleg mentioned that

> Also, we provide a test binder which was specifically designed for these type of cases where you can actually validate the real binder interaction with StreamBridge (and other components) not the mocked assumption that may actually be wrong. Please look at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/StreamBridgeTests.java for more on testing with StreamBridge.

Considering Oleg's response above and since I need to isolate the Spring Cloud Stream code (StreamBridge and anything else) to test my code, I will be looking into the test binder from Spring Cloud Stream.

BTW, I am using the latest Spring Boot (2.4.5) / Spring Cloud Train Release (2020.0.2).

Thanks,

Rubens

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking the final class (which is possible with the latest versions of mockito using the `mock-maker-inline` extension), you can wrap `StramBridge` into your class and use it in your business logic. This way, you can mock and test it any way you need.

This is a common practice for writing unit tests for code where some dependencies are final or static classes.